# Why is value getting overwritten?

Tags: c, atmel, freertos, cortex-m

First, sorry, I know this is long and people might not read it all, but I think it needs a very detailed explanation.

I'm trying to get long file names working on Chan Fat File on a Cortex M4 with FreeRTOS. I've got a weird thing going on where, for some reason, a pointer is getting overwritten by a seemingly unconnected piece of code. You'd expect a stack overflow (ha!), but my stack's massive and I've tried increasing further it from when I first encountered this issue, I really don't think it can be that.

I have this code:

```
uint16_t w, *lfn;
lfn = dj->lfn;     
*tp = fno->lfname;
while ((w = *lfn++) != 0) 
{           /* Get an LFN char */
    if (i >= fno->lfsize - 1) 
    { 
       i = 0; 
       break; 
    }   /* Buffer overflow, no LFN */
    tp[i] = (TCHAR)w;
    i++;
}
```

`lfn` is a pointer to a 16bit value. `w` is a 16-bit value.

The line `tp[i] = (TCHAR)w;` is the following in assembler:

```
6A7B        ldr r3, [r7, #0x24]
005B        lsls r3, r3, #1
68FA        ldr r2, [r7, #12]
4413        add r3, r2
897A        ldrh r2, [r7, #10]
801A        strh r2, [r3]
```

Everything is fine the first few times through the loop. `lfn` increments from 0x20009c68 in jumps of 2, just as you'd expect. However, when `lfn` gets to 0x20009c72 and the code gets to the line `tp[i] = (TCHAR)w;` it goes haywire.

The first two lines of assembler take the value of `i`, shift it left by one to get the correct offset.

The next two lines puts `tp`'s address into `r2`, then adds the contents of `r3`, which, again, is that requisite offset.

```
ldrh r2, [r7, #10] then puts w in r2
```

Finally,

```
strh r2, [r3]
```

stores w in to where `r3` is pointing to, which is the requisite place where `tp` points.

When `lfn` gets to 0x20009c72 the line last line of assembler puts 0x20000061 into `lfn`. This is the line that is causing the real issue. Previous to that, it correctly stores `r2`, which is `w`, into where `r3` is pointing. `r3` at this point contains 0x20009c48, `r2` contains 0x00000061. However, unlike previous times, this corrupts `lfn`, putting 0x20000061 in it. It is clearly affecting `lfn` itself.

The stack pointer itself throughout the execution of this piece of code does not change.

I wonder whether it is a salient point that `lfn` in `dj->lfn` is a pointer to a `uint16_t` and not a limited size array? `dj` is a structure of type DIR which is defined below:

```
typedef struct {
    FATFS*  fs;             /* Pointer to the owner file system object */
    WORD    id;             /* Owner file system mount ID */
    WORD    index;          /* Current read/write index number */
    DWORD   sclust;         /* Table start cluster (0:Root dir) */
    DWORD   clust;          /* Current cluster */
    DWORD   sect;           /* Current sector */
    BYTE*   dir;            /* Pointer to the current SFN entry in the win[] */
    BYTE*   fn;             /* Pointer to the SFN (in/out) {file[8],ext[3],status[1]} */
    WCHAR*  lfn;            /* Pointer to the LFN working buffer */
    WORD    lfn_idx;        /* Last matched LFN index number (0xFFFF:No LFN) */
} DIR;
```

WCHAR equates to an unsigned 16-bit value.

Comment: How is `tp` defined and where is it pointing to at the start of this code ?

Comment: TCHAR *tp; TCHAR equates to uint16_t.    *tp = fno->lfname; That's in the original post :)

Comment: OK - and where is it pointing to at the start of the code - it looks like it could just be an uninitialised pointer before you de-reference it ? Maybe that line *is* the error, and should instead be: `tp = fno->lfname` ?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you mean. Are you asking what tp is set to or fno->lfname?

Comment: OK - `tp` is a pointer - it's not initialised anywhere in the code that you've shown us, but you dereference it at `*tp = fno->lfname;` which is most likely a problem. I'm guessing that this line should actually be: `tp = fno->lfname;` and you're compiling without warnings enabled, so it's gone unnoticed ?

Comment: I'm not compiling without warnings. That line does give one though:

assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]. 

I tried it the way you suggested and it crashes even sooner. I haven't investigated where it crashes your way though. I should maybe say that this is not my code, but long established open source FAT file code. I realise that doesn't mean there can't be errors in it.

Comment: OK - well it's hard to guess without seeing all the code, but that line certainly looks incorrect - it's assigning a *pointer* to the first *character* of tp (hence the warning), and tp is uninitialised at that point. There may be a deeper problem, but it's most likely outside the code given above. Check any other warnings that you might be getting - it's not a good idea to ignore them.

Comment: Yes, I see what you're saying. fno is of type FILEINFO and lfname declared as: TCHAR* lfname; within that structure, so you would expect it to be written your way. Think I was blind to it because of staring at it too long. :~/

Comment: Well good luck - it sounds like you've opened a "can of worms". ;-)

Comment: Rather depressingly it was simple to solve. You were right, there was a bug in the code - a later version of the FAT file system had the line as you put it. The problem then was that you have to reserve the space necessary for the long file name. I finally worked it out by seeing that the pointer in the structure was uninitialised and found how to do that. Gah. Thanks again. :)

Comment: No problem - glad you got it sorted out!